# Eclipse crashes when opening html file with Vaadin Designer

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

I'm new to Vaadin and just tried to use the Vaadin Designer but my Eclipse Oxygen on Linux Mint instantly crashes when I create a new html form via "Vaadin 8 Design". It crashes at the moment when it tries to open the html file. The Eclipse .log doesn't report any appropriate issue.

Any ideas are appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems with old Eclipse version and GTK 3 but I am not sure they are still in the Oxygen or not. It's worth a try to run eclipse with GTK 2:

```
env SWT_GTK3=0 GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 ./eclipse -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=true -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.useCairo=true
```

Alternatively, you can put the bellow line into ***eclipse.ini*** before ***--launcher.appendVmargs***

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Source: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/designer/designer-faq.html#i-use-linux-and-the-designer-shows-strange-artifacts-or-does-not-render-the-property-view-correctly